# AngularJS basic regarding replacement content in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some HTML which looks like:

```
<custom-logo>
    <div>
        <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <custom-logo-after>
    </custom-logo-after>
</custom-logo>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can amend the custom-logo directive in Angular JS to include a link around the `img` tag so I could add a dynamic link address in Angular JS.

Comment: show us the directive please

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry very new to this.

Comment: You have a directive called `custom-logo` - We don't have this directive, so we need to see its code and template in order to help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ng-transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to do that

```
.directive('customLogo', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a href="http://www.google.com"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></a>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j09es2w8/)

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('customLogo', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
         var image =  element.find('img');
         image.attr("src","blabla.png");
        }
      };
    }
  );
angular.module('myApp', ['directives']);


<div ng-app="myApp">
   <custom-logo>
      <div>
        <img src="logo.png">
      </div>
  </custom-logo>

</div>
```

note that "blabla.png" can be a reference to you image file on your scope. 
so for instance `$scope.image = "src/images/blabla.png"`
and then replace

```
image.attr("src",$scope.image);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the existing html but can run custom angular js so looking for a way to amend the existing content